# PowerMockito gives InvalidUseOfMatchersException on superclass static method

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

I'm trying to mock this static method:

```
public abstract class Model {
   public static <Type> Type find(Class<Type> modelClass, Object id) {
     // some code
   }
}
```

called from its extended class

```
public static class Post extends Model {
}
```

by using this test case

```
@PrepareForTest(Post.class)
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class PostEditorControllerTest {
  mockStatic(Post.class);
  when(Post.find(eq(Post.class), eq(99))).thenReturn(this.post);
}
```

The test fails with `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException`, but I guess matchers are correct.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
mockStatic(Model.class);
when(Post.find(eq(Post.class), eq(99))).thenReturn(this.post);
```